# Vue 3 - Prevent event propagation on custom event handlers

Tags: vue.js, events, listener, handler, propagation

If i have a custom event handler like *@my-event* and i emit it with

```
this.$emit('my-event')
```

it calls all the events of *@my-event* from all parent components.
But i want to prevent this.
On normal event handlers like *@click*, we can simply add *.stop* behind it to prevent this behaviour.
But *.stop* does not work on custom event listeners.

Fiddle without stop: https://jsfiddle.net/xn9sq4cp/

Fiddle with stop: https://jsfiddle.net/xy18mspz/

I know i can add

```
inheritAttrs: false
```

to prevent event propagation globaly, but i dont want this.

So, how can i prevent event propagation for custom event handlers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the component from emitting the event to stop it from being bubbled up by adding this:

```js
// ...
emits: {
  'my-event': false
}
// ...
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfcvwxjs/)